# SSRS 2008 R2 Parameter from Query with Select Multiple

Tags: reporting, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

Is there a maximum number of values that you can have for a parameter in SSRS 2008 R2?  I ask this because there is a legacy report that was built a few years ago by an employee that no longer works with my company, and one of the parameters shows all people to run the report against.  The values for this parameter comes from a stored procedure.  When running the stored procedure on the server, I get 917 people back, however, in SSRS, it shows only 894 people.  I am not aware if there is any limits in SSRS for the number of values in a parameters to choose from, but I may be wrong.

It is weird because I have been running some tests, I had the stored procedure return back the string of parameters it received from SSRS and it returns them all. The matrix tablix just isn't showing all of the rows returned from the procedure or something.

I also added a textbox with the expersion =CountRows("DataSet1") and it shows the same number of rows that the stored procedure returns

Comment: I'm sure that I've seen longer lists in SSRS parameters, so my hunch is that something else is going on. Make sure that whatever is specified as the Value column for the parameter is distinct for every option returned in you SP.

Also, the rendering engine in Business Intelligence Design Studio is slightly different that on SSRS itself. Try there and see if your results are any different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You should move the additional info in the comments into the question].

The fact that =CountRows gives you the right number of rows means that these are getting returned from the dataset, so the filter isn't in the query or in the properties of the dataset.

Check the tablix properties and then the properties of each group (including the details group) for anything in the filters property (or tab.) You might be losing things there.

Comment: I am not sure what this was at all, but I started a new report from scratch and recreated everything and it seemed to work just fine after that.  I looked at the old one and there were no filters in place anywhere.  I will mark your answer as correct though since you steered me into the right direction.  Thanks!